# How to replace NAs in one column sequentially with element from a vector using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace NAs in one column **sequentially** with element from a vector using dplyr.

Here is my demo data:

```r
set.seed(123)
col1 <- runif(30)
col1[sample(length(col1), 20)] <- NA
col2 <- seq_len(30)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

```r
> df
         col1 col2
1          NA    1
2  0.69070528    2
3  0.79546742    3
4  0.02461368    4
5  0.47779597    5
6  0.75845954    6
7  0.21640794    7
8          NA    8
9  0.23162579    9
10 0.14280002   10
11 0.41454634   11
12         NA   12
13         NA   13
14 0.15244475   14
15 0.13880606   15
16 0.23303410   16
17 0.46596245   17
18         NA   18
19 0.85782772   19
20 0.04583117   20
21 0.44220007   21
22 0.79892485   22
23 0.12189926   23
24 0.56094798   24
25 0.20653139   25
26 0.12753165   26
27 0.75330786   27
28 0.89504536   28
29 0.37446278   29
30 0.66511519   30
```

I want to replace NAs in col1 by the element from the vector `Vector = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1")`

I used the following code:

```r
#1
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(col1 = ifelse(is.na(col1), vec, col1))

#2
df2$col1 <- replace(df2$col1, is.na(df2$col1), vec)
```

but I got the following result:

```r
> df2
                 col1 col2
1                  A1    1
2   0.690705278422683    2
3   0.795467417687178    3
4  0.0246136845089495    4
5   0.477795971091837    5
6   0.758459537522867    6
7   0.216407935833558    7
8                  C1    8
9   0.231625785352662    9
10  0.142800022382289   10
11  0.414546335814521   11
12                 B1   12
13                 C1   13
14  0.152444747742265   14
15   0.13880606344901   15
16  0.233034099452198   16
17  0.465962450252846   17
18                 C1   18
19  0.857827715342864   19
20 0.0458311666734517   20
21  0.442200074205175   21
22  0.798924845643342   22
23   0.12189925997518   23
24  0.560947983758524   24
25   0.20653138961643   25
26  0.127531650243327   26
27  0.753307864302769   27
28  0.895045359153301   28
29  0.374462775886059   29
30  0.665115194628015   30
```

You can see that NAs were not sequentially replaced. I expect to see NAs to be replaced by the order "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", and then cycled.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `df2 <- df; df2$col1[is.na(df2$col1)] <- vec`

Comment: Note that you are "corrupting" your data: it goes from `numeric` to `character` by setting values to strings `"A1"`, etc.

Comment: BTW, when I run your code with that `set.seed(123)`, I get a completely different `df` with 20 `NA`s and 10 non-`NA`s. (win11 R-4.2.2)